# How to customize/localize Assert messages in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

When you use `@Assert\NotBlank` constraint and the given field is empty, then you get the error:

> This value should not be blank

I would like to change this message application-wide, without changing Symfony2 source code. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cutomizing validation error messages is quite simple, but can seem tricky at first.

**Default locale**

First of all you should change the default locale of your application. In versions 2.0.x the correct value to change is `framework.session.default_locale`. For future reference, starting from 2.1.0 it'll be `framework.default_locale`. Consult [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#full-default-configuration) for correct syntax.

A locale should consist of your language and region and is defined as `language_REGION` ([list of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#Partial_ISO_639_table), [list of countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements)). The locale used in Germany for german would be `de_DE` for example.

**Validation messages**

Validation messages are hard coded in their respective [constraint classes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints).

**Translating validation messages**

Symfony uses Twig to render all the validation messages. The process itself is complicated and falls out of the scope of this question, but the important part is that each constraint message is sent through a translation filter, which depending on the user's locale (`default_locale` by default) translates the messages to the proper language.

To change any of the translations, simply copy the validation translation file from `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/translations/validators.{lang}.xlf` to `app/Resources/translations/validators.{lang}.xlf` where `{lang}` is the language part of your default locale.

Having done the former, simply change the default messages to what ever you see more fit. If the language you need support for doesn't exist, copy any translation file to the same directory and modify that file instead.

To read more about how translation works in Symfony2, visit the official documentation on [translation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html).

Comment: as of Symphony 2.1 the files are now in `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Resources/translations/validators.{lang}.xlf`

Comment: Just to update this answer to the behavior in newer symfony versions: in **symfony 2.5**, I did not have to copy the files to enable translation for the form and validation feedback messages.

I just had to ... 

a) set the desired standard locale in parameters.yml (`locale: xy`)
b) enable the translator service in config.yml (commented out by default and to be updated with your wanted fallback language - in my case "en")
`framework: translator: { fallback: "en" }`
c) make sure, default locale in config.yml is set to defined locale from parameters.yml: 
`framework: default_locale: "%locale%"`

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the instructions by gilden, you have to make sure the `framework.translator` block in `config/config.yml` is uncommented (it's commented by default nowadays). If you don't do that, you'll still end up with the original English messages.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone has doubts in 2021, here's all I had to do to switch "Error" (eng) constraint message to "Erreur" (fr):

1. Go to your  `config/packages/translation.yaml` file
2. Edit it by replacing "en" to "fr" (or your language) : [image: Image as an example of the edited code]
3. Test it on your localhost :
   [image: Image as an example of the test post-edited]

Note :

1. here is the [Symfony 5.2 doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#translation-default-locale) I used to help me out
2. All I did was set a Default_locale (!! not detect where the user comes from !!)

Comment: This is useful if your application supports a single language and you want to stick to the default messages. It's unrelated to the question though.