# Translate form_error() in Symfony2

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony, twig

I am trying to translate the form_errors in a Symfony2 generated Forms, but I do not know how to do it. I have tried it to do iqual to the other texts in the application, putting a generic label with the transations in my message.locale.yml, but it does not work.

Also I have searched info to overwrite or "theming" the form_errors label, but in the [Symfony2 definitions](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) this field is not defined.

Does anyone know how to translate error message of form in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should translate validator messages because those messages comes from there. E.g. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988133/how-to-customize-lokalize-assert-messages-in-symfony2) or [this](http://blog.geertvd.be/2011/09/01/custom-validation-messages-for-standard-validators-in-symfony2/).

Comment: I have tried and it works, but I cannot pass values to the translation. Do you know how to do that? // message="Min. {{ limit }} characters"

Comment: Those variables are usually an option of a validator constraint like the "limit" for the "Min" constraint http://4ds.hu/2i The actual values of these variables will be assigned to them in validator objects during validation http://4ds.hu/2q and will be automatically replaced by them in `ConstraintViolation::getMessage()` So you can not pass values to the validators those come from the options and the context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, you have to provide more code for us to see what could be wrong. On the other hand, 
check out *Zend's Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext*. You can find more info on Zend adaptors here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html

Comment: I can provide code, but it does not work. Seems like Symfony2 is not able to translate error fields. To use "trans" normally I overwrite the theme of the component, but this does not exists in Symfony2 definitions